# Multiple region proxy manager

Tags: proxy

I'm currently managing an NGINX proxy manager server in the US, and we're planning to deploy additional servers globally. We want to ensure that the proxy settings are synchronized across all servers. I've reviewed the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be information on how to clone settings from one server to another. Does anyone know how to achieve this synchronization?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question (and in the wrong forum -serverfault would be more appropriate)  this and maybe should be engaging someone with the expertise to set this up. I wonder if you should be looking at deployment/management pipelines.  I expect that there are heaps of solutions from custom scripts to things like puppet/chef/ansible to containers like docket, kubernetes to deployment pupelines using git.